# Setting up hyperledger sawtooth on aws

Tags: hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-sawtooth

I am new to hyperledger sawtooth,I am working on setting up sawtooth in aws using putty but validator and rest api failing to run.

Edited:The above problem is resolved.
       I run all the commands of Xo transaction family on Aws using putty,but I am 
        getting this error
         sudo xo show my-game
         Error: No such game: my-game

Comment: Please [avoid screenshots of code in your post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Answer (score 1):

The REST API failed. You can look in files `/var/log/sawtooth/rest_api-debug.log`  `/var/log/sawtooth/rest_api-error.log`

For more details on AWS and Sawtooth, see the [app developer's guide (v1.2.1)](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/1.2.1/app_developers_guide/aws.html). 
EDIT: To answer you question about playing...

You have to both create players and create a game before you can start playing XO (tic-tac-toe). For example, to create players bob and alice, type:
`sawtooth keygen bob`
`sawtooth keygen alice`

To create a game called mygame as player jack, type:
`xo create mygame --username jack`

For more details, again see the [docs (latest version)](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/app_developers_guide/intro_xo_transaction_family.html).

Comment: Updated the links. Note that the "AWS and Sawtooth" docs are currently not available for v.1.2.3, which is why I linked to v1.2.1.